# UILocalNotification firing for multiple apps

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification

I have 3 apps that I develop and all 3 have different app Ids. I have all 3 of them installed on my device (1 via Xcode, 1 via TestFlight and 1 from the app store). I am developing a new feature using UILocalNotifications in one of the apps (installed via Xcode). When the local notification fires, a notification from the other apps also show up. 1 of the app has only push notification and even that notification shows up weirdly enough ! I dont do any actions that cause notifications to be scheduled for the other apps.

I thought all local notifications were sandboxed. I do change the time on the device to cause the notifications to be scheduled.

Does anyone have any thoughts on what could be causing this?

Comment: How do they show up? In notification center? In the history?

Comment: I have it setup as banners (and in notification center) so it shows up both ways.